# Does hibernate interceptor need any configuration prior to use?

Tags: java, hibernate, interceptor, audit

I'm trying to get Audit records from hibernate using Interceptor class which extends EmptyInterceptor. My question is, does hibernate automatically configure and call methods in Interceptor class or do i have to make any configuration whatsoever in hibernate.cfg.xml or anywhere?

Comment: As for now i haven't made any configurations outside Interceptor class itself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Exactly how you configure the Hibernate Interceptor depends on how you use Hibernate in your application - Via Spring JPA etc.

Comment: Thank you. What i understood so far is that we don't have to do any additional configurations in an XML file or anywhere to make hibernate identify that we are using the Interceptor. It just gets to know that just by overridden methods of Interceptor. (Our action of overriding) 
Am i right or not clear enough?